# I took a github project where he added a button programatically, but I added it with the interface builder but it doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

> Can Someone help me with that github project how to implement in my project with some code

This code is the one where I created the button using IB builder and created an outlet for the button and changed its class to a custom class and added the toggle function and the .TouchUpInside line
And I get an error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   2017-07-03 00:51:21.630176+0530 ala[867:183071] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

when I tap on the button and in its default state its not even visible

```
import UIKit

class serchViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var menuView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var menuBtn: HamburgerButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    menuView.frame = CGRect (x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width/4, height: screenSize.height)
    self.menuBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(serchViewController.toggle(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func toggle(_ sender: AnyObject!) {
    self.menuBtn.showsMenu = !self.menuBtn.showsMenu
}


}
```

This is the original code
    import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var button: HamburgerButton! = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 38.0 / 255, green: 151.0 / 255, blue: 68.0 / 255, alpha: 1)

    self.button = HamburgerButton(frame: CGRect(x: 133, y: 133, width: 54, height: 54))
    self.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.toggle(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle  {
    return .lightContent
}

func toggle(_ sender: AnyObject!) {
    self.button.showsMenu = !self.button.showsMenu
}
}
```

the error file code is below

```
import CoreGraphics
import QuartzCore
import UIKit

class HamburgerButton : UIButton {
let shortStroke: CGPath = {
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 2, y: 2))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 28, y:2))

    return path
}()

let outline: CGPath = {
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 27))
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 40, y: 27), control1: CGPoint(x: 12, y: 27), control2: CGPoint(x: 28.02, y: 27))
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 27, y: 02), control1: CGPoint(x: 55.92, y: 27), control2: CGPoint(x: 50.47, y: 2))
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 2, y: 27), control1: CGPoint(x: 13.16, y: 2), control2: CGPoint(x: 2, y: 13.16))
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 27, y: 52), control1: CGPoint(x: 2, y: 40.84), control2: CGPoint(x: 13.16, y: 52))
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 52, y: 27), control1: CGPoint(x: 40.84, y: 52), control2: CGPoint(x: 52, y: 40.84))
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 27, y: 2), control1: CGPoint(x: 52, y: 13.16), control2: CGPoint(x: 42.39, y: 2))
    path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 2, y: 27), control1: CGPoint(x: 13.16, y: 2), control2: CGPoint(x: 2, y: 13.16))

    return path
}()

let menuStrokeStart: CGFloat = 0.325
let menuStrokeEnd: CGFloat = 0.9

let hamburgerStrokeStart: CGFloat = 0.028
let hamburgerStrokeEnd: CGFloat = 0.111

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.top.path = shortStroke
    self.middle.path = outline
    self.bottom.path = shortStroke

    for layer in [ self.top, self.middle, self.bottom ] {
        layer?.fillColor = nil
        layer?.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        layer?.lineWidth = 4
        layer?.miterLimit = 4
        layer?.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        layer?.masksToBounds = true

        let strokingPath = CGPath(__byStroking: (layer?.path!)!, transform: nil, lineWidth: 4, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .miter, miterLimit: 4)

        layer?.bounds = (strokingPath?.boundingBoxOfPath)!

        layer?.actions = [
            "strokeStart": NSNull(),
            "strokeEnd": NSNull(),
            "transform": NSNull()
        ]

        self.layer.addSublayer(layer!)
    }

    self.top.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 28.0 / 30.0, y: 0.5)
    self.top.position = CGPoint(x: 40, y: 18)

    self.middle.position = CGPoint(x: 27, y: 27)
    self.middle.strokeStart = hamburgerStrokeStart
    self.middle.strokeEnd = hamburgerStrokeEnd

    self.bottom.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 28.0 / 30.0, y: 0.5)
    self.bottom.position = CGPoint(x: 40, y: 36)
    }

    var showsMenu: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        let strokeStart = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
        let strokeEnd = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

        if self.showsMenu {
            strokeStart.toValue = menuStrokeStart
            strokeStart.duration = 0.5
            strokeStart.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.25, -0.4, 0.5, 1)

            strokeEnd.toValue = menuStrokeEnd
            strokeEnd.duration = 0.6
            strokeEnd.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.25, -0.4, 0.5, 1)
        } else {
            strokeStart.toValue = hamburgerStrokeStart
            strokeStart.duration = 0.5
            strokeStart.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.25, 0, 0.5, 1.2)
            strokeStart.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.1
            strokeStart.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards

            strokeEnd.toValue = hamburgerStrokeEnd
            strokeEnd.duration = 0.6
            strokeEnd.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.25, 0.3, 0.5, 0.9)
        }

        self.middle.ocb_applyAnimation(strokeStart)
        self.middle.ocb_applyAnimation(strokeEnd)

        let topTransform = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
        topTransform.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.5, -0.8, 0.5, 1.85)
        topTransform.duration = 0.4
        topTransform.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards

        let bottomTransform = topTransform.copy() as! CABasicAnimation

        if self.showsMenu {
            let translation = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-4, 0, 0)

            topTransform.toValue = NSValue(caTransform3D: CATransform3DRotate(translation, -0.7853975, 0, 0, 1))
            topTransform.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.25

            bottomTransform.toValue = NSValue(caTransform3D: CATransform3DRotate(translation, 0.7853975, 0, 0, 1))
            bottomTransform.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.25
        } else {
            topTransform.toValue = NSValue(caTransform3D: CATransform3DIdentity)
            topTransform.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.05

            bottomTransform.toValue = NSValue(caTransform3D: CATransform3DIdentity)
            bottomTransform.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.05
        }

        self.top.ocb_applyAnimation(topTransform)
        self.bottom.ocb_applyAnimation(bottomTransform)
       }
    }

    var top: CAShapeLayer! = CAShapeLayer()
    var bottom: CAShapeLayer! = CAShapeLayer()
    var middle: CAShapeLayer! = CAShapeLayer()
  }

  extension CALayer {
func ocb_applyAnimation(_ animation: CABasicAnimation) {
    let copy = animation.copy() as! CABasicAnimation

    if copy.fromValue == nil {
        copy.fromValue = self.presentation()!.value(forKeyPath: copy.keyPath!)
    }

    self.add(copy, forKey: copy.keyPath)
    self.setValue(copy.toValue, forKeyPath:copy.keyPath!)
}
}
```

[Project GitHub link](http://github.com/robb/hamburger-button)

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBmqn.jpg)

[IB builder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lP7s.png)

Comment: Is the `IBOutlet` connected to the storyboard? Also there is no need to programmatically add targets to storyboard buttons you can add it directly from the storyboard. 

1. Select button in interface builder
2. In the Right Inspector window click `Connections Inspector`
3. Then drag from TouchUpInside to your viewController.

Comment: I tried doing that but its not getting connected that way @HarrySingh

Comment: @HarrySingh by the why am I getting that error?

Comment: @ChetanRajagiri "it is not getting connected that way" what do you mean by that?

Comment: @J.Doe when I pull the TouchUpInside onto my button it doesn't get highlighted and doesn't try to add that event for my button

Comment: Does you view controller in your storyboard has the same class as your code?

Comment: Yes it is connected @J.Doe

Comment: Sometimes it happens when we have multiple connection to a single button. Try to remove all the connections of the button from story board and reconnect it to view controller.

Comment: @ZohaibHassan I tried that..even that is not working?

Comment: Is my code correct?? @ZohaibHassan

Comment: [error img] (http://imgur.com/a/CYBS3)

Comment: The code posted above looks fine, but the image you posted in comments is showing me error at some other place and not in the code posted above in question.

Comment: @ZohaibHassan yeah that code is from that github link..I'll update in the question..sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

There is an [open pull request](https://github.com/robb/hamburger-button/pull/7) on the linked project to make it usable from interface builder. Why not try using that fork instead of the original repo?

The reason it isn't working currently is that a lot of setup is being done in the `init(frame:)` method. That method doesn't get called when you create an object from the storyboard, `init(coder:)` is used instead. In the code above that method is empty, so none of the setup is done.

Normally you would put common setup code in a separate method and call it from both initialisers. That isn't the approach the PR author has taken, but you can always make your own fork.

As an example:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.top.path = shortStroke
    self.middle.path = outline
    self.bottom.path = shortStroke
    // plus all the other code in here...
}
```

Would become:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.commonSetUp()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.commonSetUp()
}

private func commonSetUp() {
    self.top.path = shortStroke
    self.middle.path = outline
    self.bottom.path = shortStroke
    // plus all the other code in here...
}
```

Comment: that fork also has lots of errors and the IB designables build is failed...Can you suggest me a good project to implement the hamburger icon transition

Comment: I can't no, but you could try extracting the setup code from the init method and making sure it gets called from init with coder, as I suggest. It shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: can you explain it with the code please , as I am new to development @jrturton

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing `#selector(serchViewController.toggle(_:))` to `#selector(toggle(_:))`. Looks like it's finding `nil` since you're trying to point it to a `class` `func`. You've said in the method that your target is `self` it should be pointing to a `method` in the `current` `instance`.

Comment: No its not working..[these are the errors I am getting] (http://imgur.com/a/siKgM)